# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaiYM.png)

```
import {getProviders, signIn} from "next-auth/react";

function Login(providers) {
  return (
    <div>
      <img className="w-52 mb-5" src="https://links.papareact.com/9xl" alt="" />

    {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
      <div>
        <button>Login with {provider.name}</button>
        console.log(provider.name);
      </div>
    ))}

    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const providers= await getProviders();

  return{
    props:{
      providers,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: `function Login(providers) {` should be `function Login({ providers }) {`

Comment: now  i'm getting this Error
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

 {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
     |        ^
   9 |   <div>
  10 |     <button>Login with {provider.name}</button>
  11 |   </div>

Comment: Can you post your `_app.js` file?

Comment: import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";
import {SessionProvider}from"next-auth/react";

function MyApp({Component ,pageProps:{session, ...pageProps}}){

  return(
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps}/>

    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
export default MyApp;

Answer (score 0):

import {getProviders, signIn} from "next-auth/react";

function Login(providers) {
return (

```
{Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
  <div>
    <button>Login with {provider?.name}</button>
    console.log(provider?.name);
  </div>
))}

</div>
```

);
}

export default Login;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
const providers= await getProviders();

return{
props:{
providers,
},
};
}

Comment: Server Error
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object


   7 |     
>  8 |     {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
     |            ^
   9 | <div>
  10 |   <button>Login with {provider?.name}</button>
  11 |   console.log(provider?.name);